# Resharper analyses files when solution is loaded even if solution wide analysis is off

Tags: resharper

When I open the solution I am working with, resharper takes some minutes to analyse the solution, making the IDE unresponsive.

Why does it do that if I had turned off solution wide analysis?

## edit

I have got an answer that there is no actual analyze on startup if I turned off "solution wide analysis". However, on startup, there is a red animated icon in the lower right corner of the window and if I click that, the tooltip reads "Analyzing files (8 of 431)" so the suggestion that there is no solution wide analysis is contradicted by the wording.

Answer (score 1):

there are multiple things you can try on the first hand.

have you trying reading
[this link](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/profiler/Studying_Profiling_Results__Performance_Forecasting.html)

or you can try showing the execution time for the solution analysis then you can see where it got stuck for minutes.

or you can try this too.

Go to ReSharper | Options | Environment | Performance Guide to check and quickly fix ReSharper and Visual Studio preferences that affect performance.

If you do not use solution-wide analysis, disable it or consider disabling warnings in solution-wide analysis. Even if it is disabled, you can find all code issues in your solution at any time by running code inspection for the whole solution. To configure solution-wide analysis, go to ReSharper | Options | Code Inspection | Settings.

In Visual Studio options, go to Source Control | Plug-in Selection: select None for the source control plugin. This will turn off Git or another VCS provider and improve overall performance.

Comment: But solution wide analysis is already turned off.

Answer (score 0):

ReSharper builds or updates indexes on startup. The indexes are used for basic ReSharper's functionality: navigation, refactoring, code analysis in open files, etc...

If you see IDE unresponsiveness, you can collect timeline perfomance snapshot and send it to JetBrains for investigation. Instructrions for submitting performance problem can be found here (you need to select "Performance snapshot(timeline)":
https://resharper-support.jetbrains.com/hc/en-us/articles/207243205-How-to-collect-a-performance-snapshot-and-send-it-to-JetBrains-Team